# How to Append Grades on List per student in Dictionary Python

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, append

```
Students = {}

def IslemYap():
    Input = int(input("Process Number: "))
    if Input == 1:
        StudentName = input("Student Name: ")
        for i in range(1,8):
            Students.update({StudentName:[input()]})
            print(Students)

IslemYap()
```

Im trying this but don't working. 7 times per student append grades.

Comment: The for loop is supposed to add the grades?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What does "not working" mean? Please read [ask].

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you always overwrite it and never fill the grades in a proper list.

```
Students = {}

def IslemYap():
    Input = int(input("Process Number: "))
    if Input == 1:
        StudentName = input("Student Name: ")
        for i in range(1,8):
            Students[StudentName] = Students.get(StudentName,[]) +  [input()]
            print(Students)

IslemYap()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the grades to a list and simply add it to the correspondent student in the dictionary

```
Students = {}

def IslemYap():
    Input = int(input("Process Number: "))
    grades = []
    if Input == 1:
        StudentName = input("Student Name: ")
        for i in range(1,8):
            grades.append(input())
        Students.update({StudentName: grades})
        grades = []
        print(Students)

IslemYap()
```